# How to parallelise nested FOR loops with OpenMP

Tags: c, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp, cpu

I am attempting to iterate through a large PPM file containing pixel data by iterating through the file in cells (rows x columns). I want to optimise these two FOR loops by using the `omp_set_nested` function, but I am getting the following error:

`termination test in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form`

For simplicity, I have taken away the functions relating to retrieving the data itself, and just have just included the `FOR` loops.

**Summary:** How can I keep `i < OUTER_LOOPS && i < OUTER_LOOPS` and `j < INNER_LOOPS && j < INNER_LOOPS` within the `FOR` loop conditions without getting an error?

**UPDATE:** I now realise the ridiculous mistake I was making by having `i < OUTER_LOOPS && i < OUTER_LOOPS` which is far less efficient than simply `i < OUTER_LOOPS` etc.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
omp_set_nested(1);
int i, j;
#define OUTER_LOOPS width
#define INNER_LOOPS height

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOPS && i < OUTER_LOOPS; i += 4) {     //Issue probably here
                #pragma omp parallel for
                    for (j = 0; j < INNER_LOOPS && j < INNER_LOOPS; j += 4) { //Issue probably here
                        printf("Hello world\n");
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Why checking the same condition twice? `i < OUTER_LOOPS` is more efficient than `i < OUTER_LOOPS && i < OUTER_LOOPS`...

Comment: Besides the absurdity of using `i < OUTER_LOOPS && i < OUTER_LOOPS`, don't use nested loops. Look for all the questions about them to understand why.

Comment: I mistakenly thought that without have those conditions I could not iterate through my data in a rows x columns manner. This has now solved the problem, thank you @Matthieu

Comment: @p.luck *rows x columns* iteration is done by nesting loops (usually `for`) with the outer one for rows and the inner one for columns (usually, but the other way around is possible, depending on the type of processing). It's all about nested loops, not their exit condition.

Comment: I echo @Zulan, but would add that you should also consider the "collapse" clause (and probably add a chunksize too) Note, too, that depending on what you're doing on each pixel, this may be an I/O bound problem anyway, in which case parallelising is likely futile.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks for the suggestion - I did consider "collapse(2)" for the very outer nested loops, but it's not supported on VS2017 so I didn't use it